# How to check 'fulfilled' state for Node.js event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-events

When we work with [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), we can check whether pending state is finished.

But with Node.js-events we can only add listener for some named events. How we can check whether particular event has occurred?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't directly possible, since Node.js events may be fired more than once. However, you can do something like this:

```
let happened = false;
someEmitter.once('event1', () => {
  happened = true;
});
```

However, keep in mind that this doesn't work if the event handler can't be attached immediately.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I do this. But I thought that maybe there is something built for Node.js.

Comment: Understandable, but not possible due to events firing more than once.